# How to arrange a list of elements in a panel and have auto-arrange if an element removed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I got 6 images like this in picture edit

[image]

but when I toggle the visibility of 2nd and 4th image it got empty or blank.
What I want is the other image fill the empty or image like this (not just 2nd and 4th, visibility false whenever I want):
[image]

the code I use is:

```
Bitmap gambr1 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Add_f, 32, 32);      
Bitmap gambr2 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Edit_f, 32, 32);       
Bitmap gambr3 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Delete_f, 32, 32);        
Bitmap gambr4 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.print, 32, 32);      
Bitmap gambr5 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.sheet,32,32);        
Bitmap gambr6 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.close, 32, 32);        


private void dev12_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureEdit1.Image = gambr1;
    pictureEdit2.Image = gambr2;
    pictureEdit3.Image = gambr3;
    pictureEdit4.Image = gambr4;
    pictureEdit5.Image = gambr5;
    pictureEdit6.Image = gambr6;

    if ( pictureEdit2.Visible == false)
    {                
        pictureEdit2.Visible = false; 
                       
    }
    if ( pictureEdit4.Visible == false)
    {
        pictureEdit4.Visible = false;          
    }
}
```

for each location is

```
Point a1 = new Point(162,10);
Point b1 = new Point(233,10);
Point c1 = new Point(304,10);
Point d1 = new Point(376,10);
Point e1 = new Point(447,10);
Point f1 = new Point(518,10);`
```

Comment: You can use a FlowLayuotPanel.

Comment: @shad0wk yes, if i hide i want image is easy. but what if multiple it got so many if (condition)

Comment: Also as another option you can `Dock` all picture boxes to `Left` in a `Panel`. This way also when you make one of them invisible, others will fill the space to left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx). This way when a control is invisible, other control shifts and fill the space:

- Set `Padding` of `FlowLayoutPanel` to specify the distance between the container and contents.
- Set `Margin` of controls to specify the distance between controls in the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

In the below example, I set `Padding` of `FlowLayoutPanel` to 5 and `Margin` of all `PictureBox` controls to 5 and then set `Visible` of controls to `false` by click. You see as soon as I make a control invisible, the layout changes:

[image]

Also as another option you can `Dock` all picture boxes to `Left` in a `Panel`. This way also when you make one of them invisible, others will fill the space to left.

Comment: thank for the suggestion. i will try to learn it.
that picture is dock in bottom of form using panelcontrol1 should i switch it or just use it?

Comment: While `FlowLayoutPanel` is preferred, you can also `Dock` property of `PictureBox` controls to `Left` in the `Panel`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei  the thing is the picture box is at center of panelcontrol, if iam using dock left then theres no need for me to question this maybe - no offence

Comment: When I say the `PictureBox`, I mean the control which is showing an icon. So if it's a usercontrol created using a panel that have a picturebox in it, apply what I said on that control.

Comment: my bad, i think it's still using my panelcontrol1. my panelcontrol dock on the bottom form and my `picturebox` still no dock. i learn first about flowlayoutpanel, thanks for the dock suggestion