# How to set FlowLayoutPanel contents at Center of Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, flowlayoutpanel

I have a few `Button` controls in a `FlowLayoutPanel`, and I want to set them precisely at middle bottom of `Form`.
In the image below I set the `Button` precisely at middle by setting the `FlowLayoutPanel` padding manually by 400 to left.

[image: max]

But when I try to resize or restore down the buttons wont at middle anymore because of manually set of padding.

[image: min]

Is there anything that I can do to set the buttons in middle of `FlowLayoutPanel` whenever I try to resize it. I'm following the answer base on 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718174/how-to-set-image-index-and-fill-the-image) to add and remove buttons dynamically.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using a single cell [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) which is suitable for centering the content and an auto-size [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/flowlayoutpanel-control-overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) you can achieve what you are looking for:

Perform these settings on the controls:

- Add your images to a `FlowLayoutPanel`

  - Set `AutoSize` of `FlowLayoutPanel` to `true`
  - Set `AutoSizeMode` of `FlowLayoutPanel` to `GrowAndShrink`
  - Set `Anchor` property of `FlowLayoutPanel` to `Top, Bottom`
- Use a `TableLayoutPanel` for hosting the `FlowLayoutPanel`

  - Use a single `Column` and a single `Row` in `TableLayoutPanel`.
  - Set `Dock` property of `TableLayoutPanel` to `Bottom`.

This way, when you add or remove images dynamically, all images will be shown at bottom center of the form.

Comment: hey its you again,
it works thanks man.. still have no idea about table layoutpanel with 1 column and 1 row

Comment: Take a look at [TableLayoutPanel Control Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: is it just in table layout when we use anchor top and down it settle in mid ?
what if we use other or change table layout like panel control or flow layoutcontrol when it hosting some panel to top and bottom did it settle in mid ? iam also try increasing the row and column it seems like depend on how many row and column, so one row and one column makes it best (middle)

Comment: Each cell of `TableLayoutPanel` works this way, if you set the `Anchor` of the content to `Top, Bottom` it keeps the content in middle of the cell. So we used a single cell to occupy the whole row. Each cell can contain a single control. So to host more than one control, we use a container control in cell to host more than one control in that container.

Comment: Here `FlowLayoutPanel` helps us to add or remove controls and forget about the layout. Controls will be automatically layout in a `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: mmmh, i have tried it too try to put in other than tablelayout , it wont works. and like u said if used a single cell it occupy the whole row. maybe the cons is when i try to insert many row or column and say the flow layout control got 5 button image, it only display less than 5.. thanks for your explanation sir +3

Comment: You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39047133/3110834) useful. It's about centering a control in a panel.