# How to center align multiple radio buttons in FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I'm using windows forms and trying to add multiple radio buttons on a `FlowLayoutPanel`. I might add 10-12 radio buttons dynamically and might remove them, but all the time they will be at the center of the `FlowLayoutPanel`. Currently they are being added like the picture below:
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use Flowlayoutpanel? you can simply use TableLayoutPanel and center your controls.

Comment: Anchor property might help you. (Set is to Left & Right)

Comment: Actually reading the question should help the both of you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fine-tune positions of controls in their containers you can modify their `Margin` property.

Assuming you have the controls to center in a list:

```
List<Control> ctls = new List<Control>();
foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls) ctls.Add(c);
```

You can call a function to align them:

```
void centerControls(List<Control> ctls, Control container)
{
    int w = container.ClientSize.Width;
    int marge = (w - ctls.Sum(x => x.Width)) / 2;
    Padding oldM = ctls[0].Margin;
    ctls.First().Margin = new Padding(marge, oldM.Top, oldM.Right, oldM.Bottom);
    ctls.Last().Margin = new Padding(oldM.Left, oldM.Top, oldM.Right, marge);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Call the function whenever you have added or removed a control:

```
centerControls(ctls, flowLayoutPanel1);
```

You will need to **reset** the `Margins` when you add new Buttons..

Note that I only change the outer `Margins`, not the space between. To do the latter you can calculate the space and change `Margins` for all controls:

[image]

```
void spaceControls(List<Control> ctls, Control container)
{
    int w = container.ClientSize.Width;
    int marge = (w - ctls.Sum(x => x.Width)) / (ctls.Count * 2 );
    Padding oldM = ctls[0].Margin;
    Padding newM = new Padding(marge, oldM.Top, marge, oldM.Bottom);
    foreach (Control c in ctls) c.Margin = newM;
}
```

Also do think of what shall happen when more than one row of `RadioButtons` is there! You may want to put more effort in maintinang the List(s)..

Also note that users do not like their controls to jump around a lot!

**Update:** Do have a look ar Reza's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824530/how-to-set-flowlayout-button-to-center-of-form) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39047133/3110834) for ways to achieve something like the 1st layout in a code-free way!

Comment: You can achieve such layout without writing code. If you host an auto-sized `FlowLayoutPanel` which its anchor is set to `Top` and `Bottom` in a `TableLayoutPanel` with a single cell, the controls which you add to `FlowLayouPanel` will be always aligned at center of the `TableLayouPanel`. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824530/how-to-set-flowlayout-button-to-center-of-form) contains required settings to achieve such layout. Using such settings makes the layout more reliable IMO.

Comment: A good feature of `TableLayoutPanel` with a single cell is it helps us to have content vertically and horizontally at center without writing a single line of code like mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39047133/3110834).

Comment: Anyway, your code is also working, but the OP should be careful about margins and they should apply those methods when the size of container changes.

Comment: This is intersting, indeed! - Not sure if you can stay away from code when you add a dozen RadioButtons and if you want to control the rows the go to. But the question was somewhat unclear about this..