# C# Unable to dynamicly auto-size columns evenly in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a WinForm that has a `TableLayoutPanel` control. My code will detect the number of attached monitors on screen, create a column per monitor, and then add a button for each display within each individual column in the `TableLayoutControl` so I can ensure that no matter how many monitors are attached, the buttons will appear "centered" across the form. One/two monitors renders just fine, however three monitors results in end columns not being evenly distributed.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
            int count = Screen.AllScreens.Count();
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = count;

            ColumnStyle cs = new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100 / count);
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(cs);

            this.monitorLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true;

            var buttonSize = new Size(95, 75);

            int z = 0;
            foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(i => i.Bounds.X))
            {

                Button monitor = new Button
                {
                    Name = "Monitor" + screen,
                    AutoSize = true,
                    Size = buttonSize,

                    BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,                                                  
                    BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.display_enabled,
                    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                    Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold),
                    ForeColor = Color.White,
                    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                    Text = screen.Bounds.Width + "x" + screen.Bounds.Height,
                    Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None
                };


                this.monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(monitor, z, 0);
                z++;
                monitor.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(monitor_Click);
            }
```

I've tried making the buttons smaller, and increased the form size but the last column is always smaller than the first two. I can't understand it!

Comment: [How to create a magic square using Windows Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33968993/3110834)

Comment: [How to set FlowLayoutPanel contents at Center of Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824530/how-to-set-flowlayoutpanel-contents-at-center-of-form)

Comment: To make your dynamic controls align at bottom-center of form, take a look at second linked post. You can add your button controls to an auto-sized `FlowLayoutPanel` which its anchor is set to `Top, Bottom` and is hosted in a single-column docked-to-button `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: A single-cell `TableLayoutPanel` keeps the auto-sized contents at center if you use suitable anchor for contents (for example `None` or `Top, Bottom`): [Keep a Control vertically and horizontally at Center of Container](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39047133/3110834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei) pointed me to this thread [How to create a magic square using Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33968993/3110834) which pointed me in the right direction. Updated (and working) code below. :)

```
            int screens = Screen.AllScreens.Count();
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.ColumnCount = screens;            
            this.monitorLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true;

            int z = 0;
            foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(i => i.Bounds.X))
            {
                var percent = 100f / screens;
                this.monitorLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, percent));

                Button monitor = new Button
                {
                    Name = "Monitor" + screen,
                    Size = new Size(95, 75),
                    BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,                                                  
                    BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.display_enabled,
                    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                    Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold),
                    ForeColor = Color.White,
                    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                    Text = screen.Bounds.Width + "x" + screen.Bounds.Height,
                    Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None
                };


                this.monitorLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(monitor, z, 0);
                z++;
                monitor.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(monitor_Click);
```

Answer (score 2):

Clear ColumnStyles first.

```
this.monitorLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Clear();
```

then:

```
int count = Screen.AllScreens.Count();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    ColumnStyle cs = new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, (float)100 / count);
    this.monitorLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(cs);
}

this.monitorLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true;

...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's made the last two columns more even, however all three the columns are still not evenly distributed: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/LJZBb)

Comment: Maybe its because of float parameter.

Comment: @MSL Yes, `ColumnStyles` should be cleared at first. For this problem, I'd keep button-list in bottom-center of form [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824530/how-to-set-flowlayoutpanel-contents-at-center-of-form).